Murderous woman chases teenage girls in a car
I saw a horror movie two years about a couple of hot teen girls who provoke a creepy, middle-aged woman, who then chases them through a forest and forces them to urinate in their clothes (maybe some of them) and humiliates them. As I remember the teenage girls had their own car and the woman had a car in the beginning.
She got angry because of some thing - maybe it was poo throwing, I don't remember. I think it got a rating between 5 and 6 on imdb with a few 1000 votes. But the whole film is about the woman taking revenge for some minor provocation I think the teenage girls threw feces on her car or something like that. 
The movie is from the 00's and probably American. I don't remember the title, can somebody help?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was the movie likely from? Are there any additional plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

Did she force them to pee in their clothes or did she scare them in a way that caused them to pee themselves? Not sure how someone can force a person to pee in their clothes... Was the poo throwing what caused the older woman to chase them?

I'm pretty sure she forced them in order to humiliate them. She got angry because of some thing - maybe it was poo throwing, I don't remember. I think it got a rating between 5 and 6 on imdb with a few 1000 votes. But the whole film is about the woman taking revenge for some minor provocation

It's the shoe-string budgeted Five Across The Eyes from 2005 about a group of girls lost in the woods and chased by a deranged woman. A 5-6 IMDb rating would've been generous (it got 2.7). From Wiki:

On their way home from a football game, five high school girls get lost in an area known as "the eyes". An ensuing accident with a parked SUV in a store parking lot causes the students to panic and flee the scene. A vehicle with one headlight starts to follow them until the driver traps them on a deserted road. The driver thinking that they wrecked her marriage forces the five girls from their vehicle, forces them to strip and urinate on their clothing at gunpoint.

One of the girls also flings feces at the woman's car at some point. Here's the trailer [Warning: Gory]:




You're the man! Thanks a lot.

@Jeppe No problem, but please mark it as 'solved' with the check mark.
